# Can you set everything in an MS Paint picture except what you draw to white?

Tags: microsoft-paint

**EDIT:** It says "Anonymous4" as the OP, but I just joined and my real username is SealBoi. Just keep that in mind so you know who I am when I comment on something.

I was using MS Paint to draw onto a photograph, and I've drawn a closed shape. I selected the colour I wanted to fill the shape with (as colour 1), and then I clicked on the fill with colour icon (not the other fill for shapes).

Now, it shows the bucket icon (with black paint coming out of it when black is not the colour I selected - is that of any significance?), but when I click inside the shape, nothing happens.

Upon magnifying the image, I can see the problem. Every time I click with the bucket, it fills one pixel with the desired colour. That's because the image I'm drawing onto is a photograph and due to lighting each pixel is a different colour.

Is there any solution to this? Can I change the background all to one colour? Is there any way of setting everything in the picture except what I draw to just white?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you averse to using a different tool from MS Paint?

Comment: MS Paint is not designed to handle photographs. You will want to use an advanced tool, such as PhotoShop for this.

Comment: @bertieb Hi, OP here (I asked as a guest then joined). To be honest, I'd rather not, since I need to get this drawing finished very soon, and MS Paint is the only one I have.

Comment: @SealBoi You can [merge your accounts here](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts). This is a case where using another tool might be overall *faster* and easier. Think of trying to use a frozen banana as a hammer; you might only have a smallish number of nails, but if you have to keep re-freezing the banana it'd quicker to use a hammer.

Comment: (I think I may have broken a convention on torture on that metaphor, but you get the drift)

Comment: @bertieb Hmm. The only other photo editing tool I have is Picasa 3, do you think that could do the job? I doubt it.

Comment: Download paint.net. (https://getpaint.net) its free and although not as good as photoshop, it is a whole lot better in editing photos than MS Paint is.